# Mean() not working with functions as arguments within a pie

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, mean, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I'm a beginner with R. I'm doing some exercises on data manipulation with dplyr, and I'm encountering something I don't quite understand.

I'm with an exercise which uses the 'titanic' training dataset within tidyverse. The exercise is about imputing an average each by sex to all those passenger observations which have an NA for their age.

The snippet of code that works is this one:

```
`#' Exercise 6.5
#' Use the case_when function to create a new column in the titanic dataset called imputed_age_of_passenger.
#' In this column we should have, wherever the value of the sex_of_passenger is “male” and age of passenger value is
#'missing the imputed value should be the mean age_of_passenger of only the male passengers. wherever the value 
#'sex_of_passenger is “female” and age of passenger value is missing the imputed value should be imputed with the mean 
#'age_of_passenger of only the female passengers. Otherwise, take the value of the age_of_passenger.

mean_age_male <- titanic %>% 
  filter(sex_of_passenger == "male") %>% 
  pull(age_of_passenger) %>% 
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)

mean_age_female <- titanic %>% 
  filter(sex_of_passenger == "female") %>% 
  pull(age_of_passenger) %>% 
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)

titanic <- titanic %>% 
  mutate(imputed_age_of_passenger = case_when(
    sex_of_passenger == "male" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean_age_male,
    sex_of_passenger == "female" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean_age_female,
    TRUE ~ age_of_passenger))`
```

I was trying to make the code slicker and briefer. I did not see a point in creating two auxiliary variables for the averages by sex in memory, which I don't need other than for creating the new column on the dataset. So I tried doing all in the one pipe as below:

```
titanic <- titanic %>% 
  mutate(imputed_age_of_passenger = case_when(
    sex_of_passenger == "male" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean(filter(sex_of_passenger == "male")$age_of_passenger, na.rm = TRUE),
    sex_of_passenger == "female" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean(filter(sex_of_passenger == "female")$age_of_passenger, na.rm = TRUE)
    TRUE ~ age_of_passenger))
```

However, I get the following error:

`Error: unexpected numeric constant in: "    sex_of_passenger == "female" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean(filter(sex_of_passenger == "female")$age_of_passenger, na.rm = TRUE) TRUE"`

Equally, I try to simplify the definition of the two auxiliary variables somewhat, by combining the pull() and the mean() functions in one line rather as sequences within the pipe, like this:

```
mean_age_male <- titanic %>% 
  filter(sex_of_passenger == "male") %>% 
  mean(pull(age_of_passenger), na.rm = TRUE)
```

But while the above does work, it stores NA to that mean_age_male variable, having shown the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(., na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Can someone tell me why neither of the snippets above work as intended? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the first code I think there is something wrong with the way you are trying to filter the data when assigning the value.

You can try something like the below
df["columnname for the column to perform mean calculation"][df["name of column for filter"] == "filter value"]

```
titanic <- titanic %>% 
  mutate(imputed_age_of_passenger = case_when(
    sex_of_passenger == "male" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean(titanic["age_of_passenger][titanic["sex_of_passenger"] == "male"], na.rm = TRUE),
    sex_of_passenger == "female" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean(titanic["age_of_passenger][titanic["sex_of_passenger"] == "female"], na.rm = TRUE)
    TRUE ~ age_of_passenger))
```

if you want to avoid saving the values of avg age what you can do is something to calculate the avg age then to assign the needed values like below

```
titanic %>% 
  group_by(sex_of_passenger) %>%
  summarise( Avg_Age = mean(age_of_passenger, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Now you are getting two values of Avg age.

You can assign the values manually like the below

```
titanic["imputed_age_of_passenger"][is.na(titanic["age_of_passenger"]) & titanic["sex_of_passenger"] == "male"] <- first value

titanic["imputed_age_of_passenger"][is.na(titanic["age_of_passenger"]) & titanic["sex_of_passenger"] == "female"] <- second value
```

Comment: Hey Qasim, thanks for your answer. I understand the group_by snippet, but I don't quite follow any of the other two bits of code you've made. Firstly, what's wrong about the way I'm using the filter() function within other functions of the pipe? Second, what's with these double square brackets you are using? (e.g. df['a']['b']). I know that the square brackets are used to access specific elements of an object, and that in dataframes you can call them by number indices or their header name between commas. But why two sets of brackets?

Comment: Plus, if I run your first snippet of code (fixing some missing quote marks in the names between the square brackets) I get an error: `Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"    sex_of_passenger == "female" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean(titanic["age_of_passenger"][titanic["sex_of_passenger"] == "female"], na.rm = TRUE)
    TRUE"`

Comment: Hi Dear, the issue with your filter code is filter(sex_of_passenger == "male")$age_of_passenger you are trying to filter data and then using $ with column name, this is not the correct way to use $ with column name, $ with column name is used directly after data frame and not a filter. this code means select column age  from titanic data frame when sex of passenger from titanic data set equal male titanic["age_of_passenger][titanic["sex_of_passenger"] == "male"

Comment: Can you please try following titanic <- titanic %>% 
  mutate(imputed_age_of_passenger = case_when(
    sex_of_passenger == "male" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean(titanic["age_of_passenger][titanic["sex_of_passenger"] == "male"], na.rm = TRUE),
    sex_of_passenger == "female" & is.na(age_of_passenger) ~ mean(titanic["age_of_passenger][titanic["sex_of_passenger"] == "female"], na.rm = TRUE))